# Generic Inheritance c#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, tree

I have create a generic Node class which will be used to build a tree object.  I want to inherit the attributes of this class in another.  The job class represents a SQL job which is included in a chain (tree) of jobs. The following code is giving me an error and I am not sure why.

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Node<T> parent { get; set; }
    public List<Node<T>> Children = new List<Node<T>>();

    public bool isRoot
    {
        get { return parent == null; }
    }

    public static Node<T> createTree(List<Node<T>> nodes)
    {
        if (nodes.Count() == 0)
            return new Node<T>();
     //Build parent / Child relationships
    }
}

public class Job : Node<Job>
{
    public string name {get; set;}

    public Job(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}


   List<Job> joblist = JobDict.Select(j => new Job(j.Key)).ToList();
   Node<Job>.createTree(joblist);
```

I am Unable to call createTree with the List of Jobs.  I realize changing it from List < Job > to  List < Node< Job > > works but why am I unable to do the former?  I figured because I am inheriting the node class, a List of Jobs would in fact be equivalent to a List of Node.  I am sorry if this is a very basic question but I just began with generics and inheritance and am having a hard time grasping it entirely.

Comment: I may not understand your question correctly. The method signature of `createTree` says the parameter has to be of type `List<Node<T>>`, not `List<T>`. So calling `Node<Job>.createTree(new List<Job>())` fails the signature hence you should expect a compiler error; however, `Node<Job>.createTree(new List<Node<Job>>())` satisfies the signature hence it works. Anyway, that's probably not what your are asking. Would you clarify your question please?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `List<Node<Job>>` and `List<Job>` are not co-variant.

If you're using .NET 4 you can do this.

```
Node<Job>.createTree((IEnumerable<Node<Job>>)joblist);
```

or, you can modify the **creeatetree** method definition as follows.

```
public static Node<T> createTree(IList  nodes)
{
    if (nodes.Count == 0)
    return new Node<T>();       

    //Build parent / Child relationships
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I realize changing it from `List<Job>` to `List<Node<Job>>` works
>   but why am I unable to do the former?

Because `List<Job>` does not inherit `List<Node<Job>>` even if `Job` inherits `Node<Job>`. In other words, **A inherits B does not mean `List<A>` inherits `List<B>`**.

You may need to cast each Job object to `Node<Job>` first:

```
var jobNodeList = joblist.Select(j => (Node<Job>)j).ToList();

Node<Job>.createTree(jobNodeList);
```

Comment: This is actually the answer to the problem I was getting at.  job.Parent = new Job("Parent");  Works but  job.Children = new List<Job>(); does not.  How would I alter my class definition to allow this syntax or more specifically the ability to treat a list of jobs as a list of nodes without explicitly casting them?

Comment: I'm not sure if you would agree, but how about templating it:
`public static Node<T> createTree<U>(List<U> nodes)
    where U : Node<T>
{
        if (nodes.Count() == 0)
            return new Node<T>();
        // etc...
    }`

calling it would be: `createTree<Job>(jobs);`

BTW, Please ACCEPT this answer if this is what you we're looking for :)

Answer (score -2):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but it might give you some ideas on how to make your code simpler.

It's often a good idea to keep code simple. The simplest tree structure you can make is this:

```
public class Tree<T> : List<Tree<T>> { }
```

In your case, you would extend it slightly as:

```
public class Node<T> : List<Node<T>>
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Node<T> parent { get; set; }

    public bool isRoot
    {
        get { return parent == null; }
    }
}
```

Effectively you get all of the `Children` properties for free.